# Compare XML to string?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table with an XML column. The *vast* majority of rows contain this data:

```
<X C="1"></X>
```

I would like to find any row among the millions that does *not* match this. So...

```
select * 
from DataResults 
where cast(baserentamount as varchar(250)) not like '<X C="1"></X>'
```

This returns every row. I assume there is something very simple wrong here?

**Update:** perhaps I should reverse the sense of this question - what is the *easiest* way to do the query I want, IE, match the entry in an XML column in a WHERE?

Comment: not 100% sure what you are trying to select but I think you probably need a wild card if you want to exclude rows that contain that xml, not like '%<X C="1"></X>%'

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the actual XML in your table. If you insert that xml into a table it is not the same string you think it is.

```
declare @Something table(baserentamount xml)

insert @Something select '<X C="1"></X>'

select *
    , cast(baserentamount as varchar(250))
from @Something
```

Therefore your query will very likely return every row. And it will certainly return the rows you want to exclude because the xml string has changed.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how to "look at the actual XML in your table"? I didn't make the table nor the data, all I know is that when I select cast I get exactly the string above - I cut and pasted from SSMS.

Comment: The xml you posted will not generate the same output string. Run the code I posted and see for yourself. Or is your column datatype not really xml?

Comment: It is really XML. Let's try the next field I'll have to test. It contains <X C="1" I="0"><E D="1000Y0M0W0D" P="1" A="0" /></X> and likewise fails to match.

Comment: OK. Well the string "<X C="1"></X>" when inserted in the xml datatype is no longer in the same format. It will be '<X C="1" />'. As I said, run the code I posted and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I did, and I tried the "actual" XML and it failed to match as well. As did the longer string I posted.

Comment: Hmmm works just fine if you change the where predicate to match the actual string representation of your xml. Where....'<X C="1"/>'

Comment: Not for me. Some other way to do the query? I'm not married to the CAST.

Comment: Works perfectly on three different instances (all different sql server versions) and on sql fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c9fc4/2

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, well there it is, the devil is in the details:

XML as presented:

```
<X C="1" />
```

XML after CAST:

```
<X C="1"/>
```

Not entirely obvious, nor obvious why this should be, but there it is, it's a WS problem.

Comment: Thats what the other answer is telling you I believe.

Comment: You should not use any string-based approach when dealing with XML. Many more details for the devil to sleep in ;-) Just added an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The pure XML way to handle what you need would be to create a tiny XML Schema. After that you can validate that XML column against it.

> SQL

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.xml_schema_collections 
                    WHERE name = N'MySchema' 
                    AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo'))
   DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.MySchema;

CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.MySchema
    AS N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="X">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="C" type="xsd:int" use="required" fixed="1"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>'
GO

DECLARE @validationTbl TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, Reason NVARCHAR(1024) NULL);

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<X C="1"></X>')          -- good
,(N'<X C="1"/>')            -- good
,(N'<X C="2"></X>')         -- bad
,(N'<root>Miami</root>');   -- ugly
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- Method #1
DECLARE @ID INT, @XML AS XML(dbo.MySchema)
   , @RowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl);

WHILE @RowCount > 0
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
      SELECT @ID = ID, @XML = XMLData
      FROM @tbl
      ORDER BY ID DESC
      OFFSET @RowCount - 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      INSERT INTO @validationTbl (ID, Reason)
      VALUES (@ID, ERROR_MESSAGE());  
   END CATCH

   SET @RowCount -= 1;
END;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @validationTbl;

-- Method #2
-- unfortunately, it stops at the very first error
-- TRY_CAST() shall swallow all XSD validation errors internally
-- and produce a NULL value for all invalid rows
/*
Validate Expressions (XQuery)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/validate-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
*/
SELECT TOP(4) *, TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML(dbo.MySchema)) AS Result
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY ID;
```

> Output

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                                                                                     Reason                                                                                     |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | XML Validation: Element or attribute 'C' was defined as fixed, the element value has to be equal to value of 'fixed' attribute specified in definition. Location: /*:X[1]/@*:C |
|  3 | XML Validation: Declaration not found for element 'root'. Location: /*:root[1]                                                                                                 |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Any approach to do this on string level is wrong (due to different XML layouts, which are semantically equal and therefore possible at any stage).

Try something along this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
 (N'<X C="1"></X>')
,(N'<X A="huh?" C="1"></X>')
,(N'<X C="2"></X>')
,(N'<X C="1"></X><X C="2"></X>')
,(N'<Y C="1"></Y>')
,(N'<root>some other</root>')
;

SELECT t.*
      ,CASE WHEN t.xmldata.query(N'count(/*)>1').value('.','bit')=1 THEN 'X' END MoreThanOneNodeInLevel1
      ,CASE WHEN t.xmldata.query(N'count(/*[1]/@*)>1').value('.','bit')=1 THEN 'X' END MoreThanOnAttributeInFirstElement
      ,CASE WHEN t.xmldata.query(N'/X[1]/@C != "1"').value('.','bit')=1 THEN 'X' END Attribute_X_C_isNot1
      ,CASE WHEN t.xmldata.query(N'local-name(/*[1])!="X"').value('.','bit')=1 THEN 'X' END FirstElementIsNotNamedX
FROM @tbl t;
```

The result

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| ID | xmldata                 | MoreThanOneNodeInLevel1 | MoreThanOnAttributeInFirstElement | Attribute_X_C_isNot1 | FirstElementIsNotNamedX |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | <X C="1" />             | NULL                    | NULL                              | NULL                 | NULL                    |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| 2  | <X A="huh?" C="1" />    | NULL                    | X                                 | NULL                 | NULL                    |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| 3  | <X C="2" />             | NULL                    | NULL                              | X                    | NULL                    |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| 4  | <X C="1" /><X C="2" />  | X                       | NULL                              | NULL                 | NULL                    |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| 5  | <Y C="1" />             | NULL                    | NULL                              | NULL                 | X                       |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| 6  | <root>some other</root> | NULL                    | NULL                              | NULL                 | X                       |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
```

As you can see, just the first row is `NULL` in all columns.

The idea in short:

Your XML has got
 - 1 single element at level 1
 - This element has got 1 single attribute
 - The "C"-attribute's value in the first element="1"
 - The local-name of the first element is "X"

In the sample data I added various "wrong" XML instances.
You might need to add more rules.
Hint: You can place the expression in a WHERE clause or use `XML.exist()`.

Comment: I thought about this approach even before I suggested to use XML Schema for validation. XML Schema does it declaratively, with one single outcome: valid or not. On the other hand, all the XPath rules are procedural. And when XML is a little bit more complex, the number of XPath rules will grow quickly, and we need to check them all per row.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, I do not know, how the schema check is impemented internally, but I' m pretty sure, that this is quite some heavy action too... Furthermore, I do not like the WHILE loop... Using `TRY...CATCH` to *validate* some input is rather heavy too... Well, as always: It depends... Your schema approach is very *straigth forward*, not bad in any way, though. But I'd prefer an approach with more feedback, which rule was violated. If the OP needs a simple *true/false* result, all these rules can be combined in one single *XQuery*.

Comment: Shnugo, I added Method #2 to my answer. Check it out. That's how it is suppose to work. Unfortunately, (1) SQL Server has just a stub in the documentation for validation (2) `TRY_CAST()` is not working as expected. That's why I simulated it via a `WHILE` loop.

Comment: To all. SQL Server XML stack is very far behind the current w3c standards. To make everybody's life easier, please up-vote the following suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali